# Amazon AWS EC2 transaction/event log?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

If someone terminates an instance, is there a log kept that would show when and what the instance ID and tag/name was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had previously enabled [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/), then the instance ID would perhaps be logged there. I would doubt if the tags were, though.

The only other source would be AWS Support, who might be able to pull this information.